# Continuous $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_\limits{x\to a^+}{f(x)}=\lim_\limits{x\to b^-}{f(x)}=-\infty$, then $f$ has a global maximum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

> Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that
>   $\lim_\limits{x\to a^+}{f(x)}=\lim_\limits{x\to b^-}{f(x)}=-\infty$.
>   Prove that $f$ has a global maximum.

Apparently, this is similar to the EVT and I believe the proof would be similar, but I cannot think anything related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_0\in(a,b)$ be arbitrary. From our assumptions, there exist points $a_1,b_1$ satisfying $a<a_1<x_0<b_1<b$ such that $f(x)<f(x_0)$ for $x\in(a,a_1)$ or $x\in(b_1,b)$. Also, by EVT, $f(x)$ has a maximum on interval $[a_1,b_1]$, say that $f(M)$ is this maximum. I claim this is the global maximum of the function.

Suppose otherwise, and say that $f(c)>f(M)$. Clearly $c\not\in[a_1,b_1]$, because $f(M)$ is the maximum on the latter interval. So $c\in(a,a_1)\sup(b_1,b)$. But by choice of $a_1,b_1$ this means that $f(c)<f(x_0)\leq f(M)$ (the latter inequality true because $x_0\in[a_1,b_1]$. This is a contradiction, so $f(M)$ is really a global maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Since $lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=lim_{x\rightarrow b}f(x)=-\infty$, there exists $u>0, u<b-a$ such that $\mid x-a\mid<u, and \mid x-b\mid <u$ implies that $f(x)<-1$. The restriction of $f$ on $[a+u,b-u]$ has a maximum $m$ since $[a+u,b-u]$ is compact. Thus for every $x\in R$, $f(x)\leq sup\{-1,m\}$. Thus $f$ has a maximum. $M$.

There exists $u_M$ such that $\mid x-a\mid < u_M$ and $\mid x-b\mid <u_M$implies that $f(x)<-2\mid M\mid-1$. Since $lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=lim_{x\rightarrow b}f(x)=-\infty$. Again the restriction of $f$ on $[a+u_M,b-u_M]$ has a maximum $L$, and there exists $x_0\in [a+u_M,b-u_M]$ such that $f(x_0)=L$ since $[a+u_M,b-u_M]$ is compact, in fact $L=M$.

To see this suppose that $L<M$, there exist $c>0$ such that $M-c>L$ and $M-c>-2\mid M\mid -1$. Consider $x\in (a,b)$, if $\mid x-a\mid < u_M$ and$\mid x-b\mid < u_M$ then $f(x)<-2\mid M\mid-1<M-c$ and if $x\in [a+u_M,b-u_M]$ $f(x)\leq L<M-c$, thus $M$ is not the maximum. Contradiction. done.

Comment: For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$? Really?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = -\infty$ means that $\forall m \in \mathbb{R}, \exists \epsilon_1 \ \text{s.t.}\ | x - a | < \epsilon_1 \implies f(x) < m$. Likewise, $\lim_{x \rightarrow b} f(x) = -\infty$ means that $\forall m \in \mathbb{R}, \exists \epsilon_2 \ \text{s.t.}\ | x - b | < \epsilon_2 \implies f(x) < m$.

So we can only have $f(x) \geq m$ on some compact interval $I := [a + \epsilon_1, b - \epsilon_2]$. This could of course be an empty interval. To make sure that the $f$ actually attains a value $\geq m$, choose $m = f(x)$ for some $x$, for example $m = f(0)$. This also makes sure that $a + \epsilon_1 \leq b - \epsilon_2$, so $I$ is not empty.

By the extreme value theorem, $f$ has a maximum $f(x^*)$ on the compact set $I$, and we know $f(x^*) \geq m$. Since we have $f(x) < m$ outside $I$, we know that $f(x^*)$ is a global maximum.

Comment: I only see now that this is actually very similar in spirit to Wojowu's approach.

Comment: Again to say, $f$ is not defined in any interval of the form $(-\infty, b)$, so please correct your approach...

Comment: True. I've corrected my answer, the corrections were very minor.